# EF get specific related objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a collection of objects in my EF repository called `Territories`.  A `Territory` is linked to many `Distributions`, and each `Distribution` has one `CycleID`.

How would I write a query against EF that will grab all the `Territory` objects and the associated `Distributions` that belong to a specific `Cycle`, ignoring any `Territories` that do not have any qualifying `Distributions`?

I'm picturing something like:

```
return this.entities.Territories
    .Include("Distributions")
    .Include("Reps")
    .Where(e => e.Distributions.Any(d => d.CycleID == CycleID))
    .OrderBy(e => e.TerritoryName)
    .AsEnumerable();
```

but I'm collecting bad `Distributions`.  I can see what it's doing, but I can't figure out how to make it do what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are choosing the wrong entry point to your object graph. Start with what you know (the specific `Cycle`) and work back to the items you want to retrieve (the `Distributions` and `Territories`).

```
var cycle = this.entities.Cycles.Single(c => c.CycleID == cycleID);

return cycle.Include("Distributions")
    .Include("Territories")
    .Include("Territories.Reps");
```

Depending on how you're using the result, you may want to transform it to `Enumerable<Territory>`

```
return cycle.Distributions.SelectMany(d => d.Territories)
    .OrderBy(t => t.TerritoryName)
    .AsEnumerable();
```

You may have to play around with the `Include` statements because my EF is a bit rusty.

Comment: I ended up doing something very similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var entities = new TestEntities();
        var cycleId = 1;
        var filteredDistributions = entities.Territories
                                    .Join(entities.Distributions.Where(d => d.CycleId == cycleId),
                                          territory => territory.Id,
                                          distribution => distribution.Territory.Id,
                                          (territory, distribution) => distribution);
```